# How can i generate a 3d textures from regular cell grid for volume rendering?

Tags: opengl, graphics, visualization

I need to generate a visualization of an object, for this, I plan to use a GPU ray casting technique. The information of this object is described in two txt files. One file describes the structure of this object through a regular cell grid, and the other file has the information about intensity for each cell in the grid.

The grid is described by a list of x,y,z float point in cartesian axes, which form the cells, and the second file is simply a list o float that describes the intensity for each cell.

How can I generate a 3d texture with these files for later create a volume visualization witch "volume ray casting"?

**[Edit1 by Spektre]**

Here [sample input file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NtBsJOvOy6mxDCRuiUkITJHegS1nhzYU/view):

```
1
0
0
0
1 1 1
32 32 32
-1.495980e+14
-1.402481e+14
-1.308982e+14
-1.215484e+14
-1.121985e+14
-1.028486e+14
-9.349875e+13
-8.414888e+13
-7.479900e+13
-6.544912e+13
-5.609925e+13
-4.674938e+13
-3.739950e+13
-2.804962e+13
-1.869975e+13
-9.349875e+12
 0.000000e+00
 9.349875e+12
 1.869975e+13
 2.804962e+13
 3.739950e+13
 4.674938e+13
 5.609925e+13
 6.544912e+13
 7.479900e+13
 8.414888e+13
 9.349875e+13
 1.028486e+14
 1.121985e+14
 1.215484e+14
 1.308982e+14
 1.402481e+14
 1.495980e+14
-1.495980e+14
-1.402481e+14
-1.308982e+14
-1.215484e+14
-1.121985e+14
-1.028486e+14
-9.349875e+13
-8.414888e+13
-7.479900e+13
-6.544912e+13
-5.609925e+13
-4.674938e+13
-3.739950e+13
-2.804962e+13
-1.869975e+13
-9.349875e+12
 0.000000e+00
 9.349875e+12
 1.869975e+13
 2.804962e+13
 3.739950e+13
 4.674938e+13
 5.609925e+13
 6.544912e+13
 7.479900e+13
 8.414888e+13
 9.349875e+13
 1.028486e+14
 1.121985e+14
 1.215484e+14
 1.308982e+14
 1.402481e+14
 1.495980e+14
-1.495980e+14
-1.402481e+14
-1.308982e+14
-1.215484e+14
-1.121985e+14
-1.028486e+14
-9.349875e+13
-8.414888e+13
-7.479900e+13
-6.544912e+13
-5.609925e+13
-4.674938e+13
-3.739950e+13
-2.804962e+13
-1.869975e+13
-9.349875e+12
 0.000000e+00
 9.349875e+12
 1.869975e+13
 2.804962e+13
 3.739950e+13
 4.674938e+13
 5.609925e+13
 6.544912e+13
 7.479900e+13
 8.414888e+13
 9.349875e+13
 1.028486e+14
 1.121985e+14
 1.215484e+14
 1.308982e+14
 1.402481e+14
 1.495980e+14
```

And [file format info](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yYFnKrdSK_VZOPdsj0Ot2uUTIJ2mNxgs/view?usp=sharing):

For a regular grid, without grid refinement, the amr grid.inp looks like:

> iformat <=== Typically 1 at present 0 <=== Grid style (regular = 0)
>   coordsystem gridinfo incl_x incl_y incl_z nx ny nz
>
> xi[1] xi[2] xi[3] .....… xi[nx+1]
>
> yi[1] yi[2] yi[3] .....… yi[ny+1]
>
> zi[1] zi[2] zi[3] .....… zi[nz+1]
>
> The meaning of the entries are:
>
> iformat: The format number, at present 1. For unformatted files this
>   must be 4-byte integer.
>
> coordsystem: If coordsystem <100 the coordinate system is cartesian.
>   If 100<= coordsystem <200 the coordinate system is spherical (polar).
>   If 200<= coordsystem <300 the coordinate system is cylindrical.For
>   unformatted files this must be 4-byte integer.
>
> gridinfo: If gridinfo ==1 there will be abundant grid information
>   written into this file, possibly useful for post-processing routines.
>   Typically this is redundant information, so it is advised to set
>   gridinfo =0 to save disk space. In the following we will assume that
>   gridinfo =0. For unformatted files this must be 4-byte integer.
>
> incl x, incl y, incl z: These are either 0 or 1. If 0 then this
>   dimension is not active (so upon grid refinement no refinement in this
>   dimension is done). If 1 this dimension is fully active, even if the
>   number of base grid cells in this direction is just 1. Upon refinement
>   the cell will also be splitted in this dimension. For unformatted
>   files these numbers must be 4-byte integer.
>
> nx, ny, nz: These are the number of grid cells on the base grid in
>   each of these dimensions. For unformatted files these numbers must be
>   4-byte integer.
>
> xi[1] ... xi[nx+1]: The edges of the cells of the base grid in
>   x-direction. For nx grid cells we have nx+1 cell walls, hence nx+1
>   cell wall positions. For unformatted files these numbers must be
>   8-byte reals (=doubleprecision).
>
> yi[1] ... yi[ny+1]: Same as above, but now for y-direction.
>
> zi[1] ... zi[nz+1]: Same as above, but now for z-direction.
>
> Example of a simple 2x2x2 regular grid in cartesian coordinates: 1 0 1
>   0 1 1 1 2 2 2
>   -1. 0. 1.
>   -1. 0. 1.
>   -1. 0. 1.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? You simply need a chunk of data that represents the voxels (one value for each). Hence, simply create a block of data, fill it with zero, and then add the voxels that you have in your files.

Comment: @NicoSchertler i do not know how to create these file, his structure . and i don't know how get the voxel data of the first file. 
since in the first file there are only floating points, which in a certain order represent a regular Cartesian grid, but by themselves they are single points listed

Comment: Do you know the spacing of the grid cells?

Comment: I understand that the space of the cells depends on the distance of the points that form it. Here is an example (in 2d) of how the cell is formed with the points described in the first file, [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NtBsJOvOy6mxDCRuiUkITJHegS1nhzYU/view)

Comment: Sure, it depends on the distance of the points. The question was if you know the spacing beforehand or if you need to determine it from the points. I assume the grid is regular? Your figure suggests that the grid is complete and that there are no gaps. Is this the case?

Comment: I don't know spacing  beforehand, and yes, is how yo said

Comment: see my [volumetric back ray tracer in GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092685/2521214) it uses 3D texture and in the QA linked is also the CPU side C++/OpenGL code for the 3D texture stuff which is what you are asking about ... btw Your question is missing the sample input ... how should we know how the files are organized? also where exactly you stuck?

Comment: my problem is tha i do not know how to get the voxel information for the samplig in gpu ray cating, since in the files only describe a list a float point .
Here there is an example file input.[link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yYFnKrdSK_VZOPdsj0Ot2uUTIJ2mNxgs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Honestly, I thought I had an idea of how the files are structured. But I have no idea what the numbers in the example file mean.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain the file format well.
Here the structure of the file is explained in detail:
 [link] (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1g4SfpAGrFmyO1nHi1Urv5NtnyQ4c1BIvyxMJBUmwLgA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @sebastianpinto hmm still missing the intensities ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was curious and based on your sample grid this is what I come up with:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- AMR class ver: 1.000 --------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _amr_grid_h
#define _amr_grid_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "gl\OpenGL3D_double.cpp"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/55319835/2521214
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class amr_grid
    {
public:
    // BVH file
    int iformat;        // 0,1
    int gridstyle;      // 0 regular
    int coordsystem;    // <0,100) cartesian, <100<200) spherical/polar, <200,300) cylindrical
    int gridinfo;       // 0:  1: additional info added to file
    int en[3];          // enable x,y,z?
    int sz[3];          // size of grid [cells]
    List<double> p[3];  // walls per dimension
    // misc
    double min[3],max[3];   // BBOX
    double dl;              // avg cell size

    amr_grid(){ reset(); }
    amr_grid(amr_grid& a)   { *this=a; }
    ~amr_grid(){}
    amr_grid* operator = (const amr_grid *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //bvh* operator = (const bvh &a) { ...copy... return this; }
    // render/set/load
    void reset();               // clear whole skeleton data
    void draw();                // render actual set frame
    void load(AnsiString name); // load from AMR grid file
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void amr_grid::reset()
    {
    iformat=1;
    gridstyle=0;
    coordsystem=0;
    gridinfo=0;
    en[0]=1; sz[0]=0;   p[0].num=0; min[0]=0.0; max[0]=0.0;
    en[1]=1; sz[1]=0;   p[1].num=0; min[1]=0.0; max[1]=0.0;
    en[2]=1; sz[2]=0;   p[2].num=0; min[2]=0.0; max[2]=0.0;
    dl=0.0;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void amr_grid::draw()
    {
    int i,x,y,z;

    glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.5);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    if ((gridstyle>=0)&&(gridstyle<100))    // cartesian
        {
        if ((en[0])&&(en[1])&&(en[2]))      // 3D
            {
            for (x=0;x<=sz[0];x++)
             for (y=0;y<=sz[1];y++)
                {
                glVertex3d(p[0][x],p[1][y],min[2]);
                glVertex3d(p[0][x],p[1][y],max[2]);
                }
            for (x=0;x<=sz[0];x++)
             for (z=0;z<=sz[2];z++)
                {
                glVertex3d(p[0][x],min[1],p[2][z]);
                glVertex3d(p[0][x],max[1],p[2][z]);
                }
            for (y=0;y<=sz[1];y++)
             for (z=0;z<=sz[2];z++)
                {
                glVertex3d(min[0],p[1][y],p[2][z]);
                glVertex3d(max[0],p[1][y],p[2][z]);
                }
            }
        }

    glEnd();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void amr_grid::load(AnsiString name)
    {
    int hnd,siz,adr,i,j,k;
    AnsiString lin,s;
    BYTE *txt=NULL;
    reset();
    // file -> memory
    hnd=FileOpen(name,fmOpenRead);
    if (hnd<0) return;
    siz=FileSeek(hnd,0,2);
        FileSeek(hnd,0,0);
    txt=new BYTE[siz];
    if (txt==NULL) { FileClose(hnd); return; }
    siz=FileRead(hnd,txt,siz);
    FileClose(hnd);
    // memory -> amr_grid data
    adr=0;
    iformat=str2int(txt_load_lin(txt,siz,adr,true));
    gridstyle=str2int(txt_load_lin(txt,siz,adr,true));
    coordsystem=str2int(txt_load_lin(txt,siz,adr,true));
    gridinfo=str2int(txt_load_lin(txt,siz,adr,true));
    lin=txt_load_lin(txt,siz,adr,true); i=1; for (j=0;j<3;j++) en[j]=str2num(str_load_str(lin,i,true));
    lin=txt_load_lin(txt,siz,adr,true); i=1; for (j=0;j<3;j++) sz[j]=str2num(str_load_str(lin,i,true));
    for (j=0;j<3;j++) for (p[j].num=0,i=0;i<=sz[j];i++) p[j].add(str2num(txt_load_str(txt,siz,adr,true)));
    // BBOX
    for (j=0;j<3;j++) for (min[j]=max[j]=p[j][0],i=0;i<=sz[j];i++)
        {
        if (min[j]>p[j][i]) min[j]=p[j][i];
        if (max[j]<p[j][i]) max[j]=p[j][i];
        }
    double q[3];
    vector_sub(q,max,min);
    dl=3.0*vector_len(q)/double(sz[0]+sz[1]+sz[2]);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This just loads and draws the grid. However I expect you got the 3D texture file containing the cells intensities so simply use that as a color for a box and change the draw routine that will render cells as a box with color from your texture. the corner points of a box for any cell are 8 combination of these coordinates:

```
x: p[0][i],p[0][i+1]
y: p[1][i],p[1][i+1]
z: p[2][i],p[2][i+1]
```

you can adapt mine `glBox` (beware its `float` but code above uses double ...):

```cpp
void glBox(GLfloat x0,GLfloat y0,GLfloat z0,GLfloat xs,GLfloat ys,GLfloat zs)
    {
    xs*=0.5;
    ys*=0.5;
    zs*=0.5;
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glNormal3f(+1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glVertex3f(x0+xs,y0-ys,z0-zs);
    glVertex3f(x0+xs,y0+ys,z0-zs);
    glVertex3f(x0+xs,y0+ys,z0+zs);
    glVertex3f(x0+xs,y0-ys,z0+zs);

    glNormal3f(-1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glVertex3f(x0-xs,y0-ys,z0+zs);
    glVertex3f(x0-xs,y0+ys,z0+zs);
    glVertex3f(x0-xs,y0+ys,z0-zs);
    glVertex3f(x0-xs,y0-ys,z0-zs);

    glNormal3f(0.0,+1.0,0.0);
    glVertex3f(x0-xs,y0+ys,z0+zs);
    glVertex3f(x0+xs,y0+ys,z0+zs);
    glVertex3f(x0+xs,y0+ys,z0-zs);
    glVertex3f(x0-xs,y0+ys,z0-zs);

    glNormal3f(0.0,-1.0,0.0);
    glVertex3f(x0-xs,y0-ys,z0-zs);
    glVertex3f(x0+xs,y0-ys,z0-zs);
    glVertex3f(x0+xs,y0-ys,z0+zs);
    glVertex3f(x0-xs,y0-ys,z0+zs);

    glNormal3f(0.0,0.0,+1.0);
    glVertex3f(x0+xs,y0-ys,z0+zs);
    glVertex3f(x0+xs,y0+ys,z0+zs);
    glVertex3f(x0-xs,y0+ys,z0+zs);
    glVertex3f(x0-xs,y0-ys,z0+zs);

    glNormal3f(0.0,0.0,-1.0);
    glVertex3f(x0-xs,y0-ys,z0-zs);
    glVertex3f(x0-xs,y0+ys,z0-zs);
    glVertex3f(x0+xs,y0+ys,z0-zs);
    glVertex3f(x0+xs,y0-ys,z0-zs);

    glEnd();
    }
```

to `x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1` form or write an VBO or whatever ...

**PS.**

I also use mine dynamic list template so:

`List<double> xxx;` is the same as `double xxx[];`

`xxx.add(5);` adds `5` to end of the list

`xxx[7]` access array element (safe)

`xxx.dat[7]` access array element (unsafe but fast direct access)

`xxx.num` is the actual used size of the array

`xxx.reset()` clears the array and set `xxx.num=0`

`xxx.allocate(100)` preallocate space for `100` items

and the **C++** code is **VCL** based so you need to rewrite AnsiString to string type you got at your disposal. Also I used mine own string routines for loading lines,string and converting to numbers so you need to port that too but I assume you already got a loader ...

btw this is the output for the simple sample file in the fileformat description:

[image: screenshot]